# Will Python multiprocessing work inside a single docker container?

Tags: python, multithreading, docker, multiprocessing

I have a Django web app served by apache2 and mod_wsgi in daemon mode, the same way as described in Django's [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#using-mod-wsgi-daemon-mode). The app is hosted in AWS and is not dockerized.

However, now we need to do an on-prem deployment on one of our customer’s server and we decided to use Docker for easier deployment. I have been using Docker on this project for a while but only for development and never for production.

Since the app is using both Python's multithreading for blocking operations and multiprocessing for CPU-bound tasks. Also, Apache2 is spawning multiple processes to serve multiple requests at the same time.

Will there be any problem with multiprocessing if the app is running in a **single docker container**? Will it be able to spawn multiple processes and utilize **multiple cores** of the host machine?

Comment: Yes, a docker container can use multiple cores. But this can be configured by whoever deploys the container (controlling resource consumption is one of the selling points of containers after all), so they may need to make adjustments (to their deployment configuration, not to the application).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify how much resources should a container consume from the host.
Also by default a container has unlimited access to the host's memory and CPU.

Based on the above I'd say that you are pretty safe using multithreading and multiprocessing inside a container, and by safe I mean functionality-wise.

You can read about the resource constraints in the official documentation here: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/